# Problem with passing equations to ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, evaluation

I generate a list of equations by this command:

```
lines = Flatten[Table[Cos[alpha] x + Sin[alpha] y == c, {alpha, 0, 2 Pi, Pi / 2}, {c, 0, 10, 5}]]
```

This correctly returns the list of line equations in plane:

```
{x == 0, x == 5, x == 10, y == 0, y == 5, 
 y == 10, -x == 0, -x == 5, -x == 10, -y == 0, -y == 5, -y == 10, 
 x == 0, x == 5, x == 10}
```

However, when i call `ContourPlot[lines, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]`, nothing is displayed.

But when I copy the result list directly into the `ContourPlot` like this:

```
ContourPlot[{x == 0, x == 5, ... , x == 10}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

Then the lines are plotted correctly.

I am quite new to Mathematica, and I am not really sure what causes this problem. It is quite probable that I misunderstood something, so I will appreciate help of more advanced users.

Comment: `ContourPlot[Evaluate@lines, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]` Compare `Trace[ContourPlot[lines, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], ContourPlot]` with `Trace[ContourPlot[Evaluate@lines, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], ContourPlot]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common beginner problem. All Mathematica plotting functions do not evaluate their arguments normally because they have been given the attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html). That means you must give pass them the entire expression or pre-evaluate the symbol holding the expression. Try

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[lines], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

which will work.